How to convert a price with exchange rate from different dataframe
I have 3 dataframes.
In the 1st one I have the price with id_share as columns
In the 2nd one I have the id_share and the currency of cotation
In the 3rd one I have the exchange rate with the currency name as column
My question is simple: how to convert the price with the exchange rate.
My original data has more columns in fund_price and rows df_fund_carac.
import pandas as pd 

fund_price = pd.DataFrame({1 : [100, 100, 110, 120, 120], 
                           2 : [100, 99, 101, 102, 103], 
                           5 : [10, 10, 11, 10, 10]}, 
                          index= pd.date_range(start='2024-12-31', freq='B', periods=5), 
                          
                          )
fund_price.columns.name = 'id_share'
fund_price.index.name = 'date_price'


# Créez un dataframe à partir du dictionnaire
df_fund_carac = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "id_share": [1, 2, 5],
    "currency": ["EUR", "USD", "JPY"] }
    )

fx_price = pd.DataFrame({'EUR' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                        'USD' : [1.00, .99, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03], 
                        'JPY' : [100, 100, 110, 100, 100]}, 
                          index= pd.date_range(start='2024-12-31', freq='B', periods=5), 
                          
                          )
fx_price.columns.name = 'currency_base'
fx_price.index.name = 'date_price'


Could you edit your question with what your expected output is?

Answer was edited with to_dict()

First rename columns by df_fund_carac and then multiple by fund_price:
out = (fx_price.rename(columns=df_fund_carac.set_index('currency')['id_share'].to_dict())
               .mul(fund_price))
print (out)
currency_base    1       2     5
date_price                      
2024-12-31     100  100.00  1000
2025-01-01     100   98.01  1000
2025-01-02     110  102.01  1210
2025-01-03     120  104.04  1000
2025-01-06     120  106.09  1000

Details:
print (fx_price.rename(columns=df_fund_carac.set_index('currency')['id_share'].to_dict()))
currency_base  1     2    5
date_price                 
2024-12-31     1  1.00  100
2025-01-01     1  0.99  100
2025-01-02     1  1.01  110
2025-01-03     1  1.02  100
2025-01-06     1  1.03  100

